# Is there a framework similar to the EditorKit, in the JavaFX?

Tags: javafx-2

Is anyone aware of the similar framework based on JavaFX?

I was looking through the JavaFX API. Searched the web for third-party library that offers similar functionality, but failed to find anything remotely similar to the EditorKit...

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the HTMLEditor, but unfortunately there is no nice EditorKit framework such as we have in SWING... :(

Answer (score 1):

There is HTMLEditor for HTML editing, if needed. By default JFX doesn't provide anything similar.

RFE : javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-30318

Question from developer : "what is missing from what we offer presently?" you (and anybody who wants) can comment on it in the issue. It is closed as not an issue for now, as, there not enough info about needs of such extensions.